# Could not load large images as textures

Tags: iphone, ios5, opengl-es, ios-simulator, textures

I am working on an imaging project. Within that project the image is loaded, displayed and significant other functions will be done on it.

But I have a problem regarding that I could not load large images from the iPhone's gallery or even from the camera roll.

Within the simulator its working very well but not on the iPhone.

My imageView dimensions are like 320x358;

Here I want to use the user selected Image but I can't use here... I have got an error OpenGL: Set [error 1281]
**Assertion failed:** (0), function Set, file /Desktop/.....AppName/**TexFrameBuffer.mm**,

And in TexFrameBuffer.mm code is working very well in Simulator but not in actual device.

Even Height=2048 and width=4096 also supported.

How can I load large images on the iPhone?

Comment: Which iPhone model are you trying this on?

Comment: To follow on Till's question, the maximum texture size of non-A5 devices (everything older than the iPad 2) is 2048x2048. The Simulator runs on vastly different hardware on your Mac, so it's all but useless for doing OpenGL ES testing.

Answer (score 0):

For Temporary solution, first two uncheck `CHECK_GL_ERRORS();` function in FrameBuffer.m 's method `void FrameBufferUtils::Create(FrameBuffer& buffer, int width, int height) and void FrameBufferUtils::Set(const FrameBuffer& buffer)`